# Why do I get a NullPointerException by creating a subclass "Square" which extends an abstract class "Figure"?

Tags: java

I made an abstract class called "Figure" which has a subclass "Square"

```
public abstract class Figure {

public abstract float area();

public class Square extends Figure {

    private float x, y, l;

    public Square (float x, float y, float l) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.l = l;
    }

    public float area() {
        return l*l;
    }
}
}
```

Then I created a test

```
class FigureTest {

Figure figure;
Square square;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    square = figure.new Square(3, 4, 5); //this causes a NullPointerException
}
}
```

But I obtained a NullPointerException and I don't know why. What should I do?

Comment: `Square` is a nested class of `FIgure`, not just a subclass - very *strange* construct, probably wrong - so it needs an instance of `Figure` which you did not create - I suggest to move the class to an own file or at least make it static

Comment: Should I create a separate class "Square" which is outside "Figure" instead of inside "Figure"?

Comment: you can't since `Figure` is `abstract` // see edited comment above

Comment: So the error was the nested class? Making "Square" as nested class of "Figure" has no sense? I must create a separate class "Square" which extends "Figure"?

Comment: exactly (according the meaning of the class names) - sometimes it could be right to use nested classes, which kind of mean that the inner class is part of the outer one (and the inner needs an outer one (unless marked as `static`))

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, firstly your code is conventionally incorrect. Although *Square* is a subclass/childclass of *Figure* but it can never be used to instantiate *Figure* class. This is because *Square* is nested inner class of *Figure* class and to instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

But instantiating the outer class in your case is not possible as it is abstract class (which can only be instantiated with the constructor of its child class). One more thing I'd like to point out here is that in one java file you can have only one public class and rest other classes have **default** access modifier.

Now coming to the correct syntax of above code, it could look something like this:

```
public abstract class Figure {
  public abstract float area();
  }

class Square extends Figure {
private float x, y, l;

public Square (float x, float y, float l) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.l = l;
}
@Override
public float area() {
    return l*l;
}
}
```

Now you can easily instantiate *Figure* class as follows:

```
class FigureTest {

Figure figure;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
 figure= new Square(3, 4, 5);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `figure.new` but figure is not initialized at that time. So you call effectively `null.new` which cannot work because null has no such operator. First you have to assign an object instance to figure, then you can use it.

But as user85421 already wrote, the real problem cause is possibly that strange nesting. I see no reason here why to do it. You should fix the indentation then the mistake would be more obvious.

If `Square` would be outside `Figure` then you could write

```
square = new Square(3, 4, 5)
```

which would not produce the exception.